# I closed this window in Code::Blocks

Tags: codeblocks

I closed this window and I don't know how to reopen it, any help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to "View" menu of C::B and click on "Manager".

Or... faster solution solution is keyboard shortcut: SHIFT + F2